# NestJS kills Kafka client after finished request but before sending out all messages

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, promise, nestjs, grpc

I have a scenario like this:

1. User creates a new message for a set of emails.
2. The message goes to a `newsletter service`.
3. The `newsletter service` prepares the list of emails and sends out a single Kafka message for every email to `email service` to send out emails.
4. The `newsletter service` returns list of users that will get the emails.

In result, I get only one message sent out with a list of X users that should get the new message. My first guess was that `NestJS` is killing the process after returning a response, so from this:

```
  users.forEach((email) => {
    this.client.emit("new_message.created", {
        email,
        content
      })
  });

  return users;
```

I went to something like this:

```
  const emitter = users.map(async (email) => {
    const call$ = this.client.emit("new_message.created", {
        email,
        content
      })
    await firstValueFrom(call$);
  });

  return Promise.all(emitter).then(() => users);
```

This works, but forces the gRPC response to wait until all the messages are actually sent to Kafka by the Kafka client. How can I trigger a process that can do that in the background? Should I use the [NestJS Queues](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/queues)?